# What does IH cannot be used as a hint. in Coq mean when using eauto giving it the induction hypothesis directly?

Tags: coq

Saw related question [Lemma cannot be used as a hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237337/lemma-cannot-be-used-as-a-hint) but didn't seem super useful + seemed better to ask new that ask unrelated questions to posters there. I tried doing the trivial lemma:

```
  From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.
  Require Import ZArith.
  From Hammer Require Import Tactics.
  From Hammer Require Import Hammer.

  Theorem n_plus_0_eq_n_sketch1:
  forall n:nat,
    n + 0 = n.
  Proof.
    have IH: forall P : nat -> Prop, P 0 -> (forall n : nat, P n -> P n.+1) -> forall n : nat, P n. by apply nat_ind. (* succeeds *)

    
    (* close target with guessed lemmas **)
    (* by sauto use: IH. *) (* fails *)
    by eauto using IH. (* Gives error, IH cannot be used as a hint. *)
```

but the `eauto` tactic gives the error:

```
IH cannot be used as a hint.
```

Why is that? What's wrong with the lemma I am giving it?

I've had it work in other cases so I'm puzzled:

```
  Theorem add_comm_eauto_using:
    forall n m: nat,
      n + m = m + n.
    Proof.
      intros. 
      assert (H: forall n, n + 0 = n) by eauto using n_plus_zero_eq_n.
      assert (H': forall n m, S (n + m) = n + S m) by eauto using Sn_plus_m_eq_n_plus_Sm.
      induction n.
      - eauto using H, H'.
      - 
      (* auto using IHn, H, H'.  *)
      simpl.
      (* auto using IHn, H, H'. *)
      rewrite IHn.
      auto using H, H'.
    Qed.
```

Is it some detail of how eauto like it can't unify the goal and my lemma or something?

---

ref:

- [Lemma cannot be used as a hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237337/lemma-cannot-be-used-as-a-hint)

Answer (score 0):

`eauto` works by matching head-symbols. Unfortunately the
head symbol of `IH` is a variable `P` so this is why you are getting an error (see [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/automatic-tactics/auto.html#coq:exn.%E2%80%98qualid%E2%80%99-cannot-be-used-as-a-hint))

This is accepted but does not solve the goal

```
have IH1 := IH (fun n => n + 0 = n).
eauto using IH1.
```